# Acceso a posiciones de Datagrama

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo un problema para acceder a un elemento de un datagrama para poder modificarlo, según la documentación con la que estoy trabajando no consigo que python acceda debidamente al elemento para poder editarlo. Por ejemplo me gustaría cambiar un nombre de la columna Nombre como tengo en mi ejemplo ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
media = 0
bbdd = {
    "Nombre":["Juan","Fran","Jose","Celia","Alba","Adriana","Tomás"],
    "Edad":[23,32,41,29,30,18,46],
    "Género": ["H","H","H","M","M","M","H"],
    "Provincia":["Burgos","Madrid","Murcia","Alicante","Murcia","Granada","Murcia"],
    "Hijos":[1,0,3,2,1,0,1],
    "Mascotas": [0,0,1,4,2,1,1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(bbdd)

print("DATAGRAMA DE BBDD")
print("---------------------------")
print(df)
print("---------------------------")
for j in df["Edad"]:
    media += j
#para conocer el número de filas de un datagrama usamos len(datagramadeturno.index)
largo=len(df.index)
media = round(media/largo,2)
#Acceso por posiciones al datagrama
df.iloc[1,0] = "Francisco"
#print(df.iloc[:2,:6])
print(df.iloc[3,0])
for i in df["Nombre"]:
    print(i)
    if(i == "Celia"):
        print("encontrado")
        df["Nombre"][1]="Laura"
```

Comment: ¿No te sirve `df.Nombre = df.Nombre.replace("Celia", "Laura")` en vez del bucle que busca el nombre para cambiarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hice algunas modificaciones en tu código. Arme también una función para el promedio. Le quite matplotlib porque no se estaba usando en este caso.

```
import pandas as pd

media = 0
bbdd = {
    "Nombre":["Juan","Fran","Jose","Celia","Alba","Adriana","Tomás"],
    "Edad":[23,32,41,29,30,18,46],
    "Género": ["H","H","H","M","M","M","H"],
    "Provincia":["Burgos","Madrid","Murcia","Alicante","Murcia","Granada","Murcia"],
    "Hijos":[1,0,3,2,1,0,1],
    "Mascotas": [0,0,1,4,2,1,1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(bbdd)

print("DATAGRAMA DE BBDD")
print("---------------------------")
print(df)
print("---------------------------")

def edadPromedio():
    edades = df["Edad"]
    media = sum(edades)/len(edades)
    print("La edad promedio es: ", media)

edadPromedio()
print()

def cambiarNombreEnBBDD(nombre, nuevoNombre):
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df["Nombre"][i] == nombre:
            df["Nombre"][i] = nuevoNombre
            break
    print("DATAGRAMA DE BBDD")
    print("---------------------------")
    print(df)
    print("---------------------------")

cambiarNombreEnBBDD("Celia","Mike")
```

Queda de este datagrama:

```
DATAGRAMA DE BBDD
---------------------------
    Nombre  Edad Género Provincia  Hijos  Mascotas
0     Juan    23      H    Burgos      1         0
1     Fran    32      H    Madrid      0         0
2     Jose    41      H    Murcia      3         1
3    Celia    29      M  Alicante      2         4
4     Alba    30      M    Murcia      1         2
5  Adriana    18      M   Granada      0         1
6    Tomás    46      H    Murcia      1         1
---------------------------
La edad promedio es:  31.285714285714285
```

Pasaría a este nuevo con la modificación de "Nombre":

```
    Nombre  Edad Género Provincia  Hijos  Mascotas
0     Juan    23      H    Burgos      1         0
1     Fran    32      H    Madrid      0         0
2     Jose    41      H    Murcia      3         1
3     Mike    29      M  Alicante      2         4
4     Alba    30      M    Murcia      1         2
5  Adriana    18      M   Granada      0         1
6    Tomás    46      H    Murcia      1         1
---------------------------
La edad promedio es:  31.285714285714285
```

Espero sea de utilidad. Saludos.